# Fetching values based on Mapping table that uses ids from two different tables

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm making an app for illness detection. It is kind of a basic app with basic UI for learning purpose and I'm using SQLite Database to fetch symptoms and diseases from it.  I have three tables in my database one is Symptoms_table it has the following attributes:

```
Symp_id  symptoms
"1"      "cold"
"2"      "fever"
"3"      "headache"
"4"      "vomit"
"5"      "weakness"
"6"      "bodypain"
"7"      "stomachache"
"8"      "loosemotion"
```

I have another table called Disease table it has the following attributes:

```
 Dis_id   Disease
  "1"     "Jaundice"
  "2"     "Malaria"
  "3"     "Typhoid"
  "4"     "ChickenPox"
```

And I have a third table for mapping the ids from both of these tables. The table name is "Map" and it has the following attributes:

```
sym_id  dis_id
 "1"    "2"
 "1"    "4"
 "2"    "1"
 "2"    "2"
 "2"    "3"
 "2"    "4"
 "3"    "1"
 "3"    "2"
 "3"    "4"
 "4"    "1"
 "4"    "3"
 "5"    "1"
 "5"    "2"
 "5"    "3"
 "5"    "4"
 "6"    "2"
 "6"    "4"
 "7"    "1"
 "7"    "3"
 "8"    "1"
 "8"    "3"
 "8"    "4"
```

I have already tried using joins like LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and INNER JOIN but I didn't get what I want to. Actually, I want the symptoms columns from Symptoms_table and Disease column from Disease_table based on the ids that are mapped in the Map table. So that I could display diseases on the based on symptoms selected in my app and map symptoms based on the diseases in an expandablelistview. I meant to work both ways. I'm still learning to work with these complex SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to select from both tables, in this solution I'll use [alias](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/), one of this would either work or give you a cross join but wouldn't hurt to try:

```
SELECT S.symptoms, D.disease
FROM Symptoms_table S, Map M
FULL OUTER JOIN Disease_table ON S.symp_id = M.sym_id
```

OR

```
SELECT S.symptoms, D.disease
FROM Symptoms_table S, Map M, Disease_Table D
WHERE S.Symp_id = M.sym_id and M.dis_id = D.Disease
```

This should put you on the right track at least..